# How to check the Java Program flow?

Tags: java

How to see the program flow in java like in C language while using TurboC compiler by pressing  F7 we can know the control flow so is there any facility available for java?

Comment: Turbo C?  Is it 1990?

Comment: Use whatever debugger is available in your IDE.

Answer (score 5):

Run the code in Debug mode with break points.

Comment: what is a break point?

Comment: Read the article in the link: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: @user2604572 Essentially, a "break point" is something you can learn about by typing it into Google and clicking the first result (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) instead of asking somebody here to re-explain it for you because you're too lazy to do such a minimal amount of research on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eclipse for debugging java programs.

[Please check this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html)